# Are there any impediment in the Apache License 2.0 to sell software?

Tags: licensing, open-source, apache-license

If my project uses a part of the **other person protected by the Apache License 2.0 code**, I can sell it and **keep as open source** or there is any impediment to sell? The license itself I think very confused, especially when only option in English.

Comment: When you have more questions about the Apache license, you might want to commit to the proposal for [Open Source Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apache License has nothing to say about buying or selling software.  It neither endorses nor prohibits the sale of software so licensed.